# Autocomplete items added to autocomplete list does not show after saving the file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/completions-sample) sample seems to work fine before saving. Having "Untitled-1" works fine where as after saving it to "test.py" the item does not seem to have been added to the autocomplete list. I have run "npm install" in the folder multiple times but that does not seem to help. Here are the file extensions that does not work:

- .ts
- .c
- .cpp
- .js
- .py
- .sh

Extensions that does work:

- No extension (unsaved9
- .txt

I am running this on:
- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- vscode 1.41.0

**Edit:**

I managed to reproduce the problem on my Windows machine. Instructions for reproduction:

1. Clone this Git
2. Run "npm install" in completions-sample folder
3. Open completions-sample folder in vscode
4. Choose "Start Debugging" under "Debug" to run the extension
5. Create new file and do not save.
6. Press ctrl+shift+p and choose "Trigger Suggest". A menu should pop up with items from the extension code such as "Hello World!".
7. Give the file an extension by saving such as ".py". Repeat step 5 and the menu will not contain any custom autocomplete items.

On this I am running:

- Windows 10
- Fresh install of vscode 1.41.1

Answer (score 0):

I asked for help on the official vscode repo. Apparently you need to change the language identifier when adding a autocomplete item. It is set to "plaintext" by default meaning that your autocomplete items only will show up for plaintext documents.

```
let provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('plaintext', {

    provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext) {

        // a simple completion item which inserts `Hello World!`
        const simpleCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('Hello World!');

        // return all completion items as array
        return [
            simpleCompletion
        ];
    }
});
```

If I want the items to show up for python I can find its language ID on [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) link and change the code to:

```
let provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('python', {

    provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext) {

        // a simple completion item which inserts `Hello World!`
        const simpleCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('Hello World!');

        // return all completion items as array
        return [
            simpleCompletion
        ];
    }
});
```